# How to replace element's attr href with each ? // strip url

Tags: jquery, href, each, attr

im trying to change href with each method,

[here is demo, inspect a, you'll see there is no change](http://jsfiddle.net/nUsWT/5/)

html:

```
<a href="#/news">News</a>
<a href="#/news/detail">Detail</a>
<a href="#/sport">Sport</a>
<a href="#/sport/football">Football</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href').replace('#/',''); //tried to erase #/ from all hrefs
});​
```

Comment: You can't chain replace to attr like that; just get the href as a variable with attr as a getter, do the replace, and then pump it back out again with attr as a setter. (or like elclanrs, I suppose you can just do the setter all in one!).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code you posted will get the value as a `string` then properly `replace` the values but it immediately discards the result.  You need to pass in the replaced value to `attr`.  Try the following

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', value.replace('#/',''));
});​
```

Comment: interestingly this is not running in to my plugin /: ill try again

Answer (score 6):

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$(this).attr('href', href.replace('#/',''));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check href value and make condition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('href');
    if(value=='http://google.com')
    {
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://youtube.com');
    }
});​
</script>
```