# How can I strip certain html tags out of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, text

I have a `<textarea>` that a user types something in, and they are allowed to type html. Once they are done typing, the `<textarea>` changes back to a `<span>` that contains what they just typed. However, I want to strip out certain tags such as `<script>`, `<div>`, etc... before I put it back into the `<span>`.

Comment: if you want to remove only specific tags, you can use regex. or do you want to remove all tags?

Comment: I only want to remove specific tags and their contents.

Comment: this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369182/how-to-replace-elements-attr-href-with-each-strip-url

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Believe it or not you can (safely) do this with the browser's built in HTML parser. Simply create a new div with `document.createElement`, toss the contents of the textarea into the div using `innerHTML`, and presto, you've got a full blown DOM to work with. And no, scripts contained within this div will *not* be evaluated.

Here's a simple example that strips from an element all tags that do not appear in an `ALLOWED_TAGS` list.

```
var ALLOWED_TAGS = ["STRONG", "EM", "BLOCKQUOTE", "Q", "DEL", "INS", "A"];

function sanitize(el) {
    "Remove all tags from element `el' that aren't in the ALLOWED_TAGS list."
    var tags = Array.prototype.slice.apply(el.getElementsByTagName("*"), [0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (ALLOWED_TAGS.indexOf(tags[i].nodeName) == -1) {
            usurp(tags[i]);
        }
    }
}

function usurp(p) {
    "Replace parent `p' with its children.";
    var last = p;
    for (var i = p.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var e = p.removeChild(p.childNodes[i]);
        p.parentNode.insertBefore(e, last);
        last = e;
    }
    p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}​
```

As mentioned, you'll have to create an empty div container to use this. Here's one example application of the technique, a function to sanitize strings. Please note, however, that "sanitize" is at this time a misnomer--it will take a lot more work (cleaning attribute strings and such) before this "sanitizer" will output HTML that is truly safe.

```
function sanitizeString(string) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = string;
    sanitize(div);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This is great. I've found a problem with it though. If I have something like `<b><span><script>...</script></span></b>` Then the script will execute. For some reason, if you have nested tags like this, the second illegal tag will never be deleted. I could have something like `<asdf><input type="text" /></asdf>` and the input will appear, even if the first tag isn't even a real tag.

Comment: user1359900, you're absolutely right. I had to convert the node list into an array so it's not messed with by the usurp function. It should work as intended now.