# Disable some html output in input box

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have an input that works like a chat box. (The user types something in the input and it outputs on the page). I just noticed that the user can also use **html tags** in my input box to change the output.

Example: If I typed `<b>Hello</b>`, the output text would be bolded and so on...

I don't want to disable this function completly. But there are some tags that I don't want outputted (example *h1* or *h2*...). I think that's it's possible with regex (not sure how too proceed with that though), but I feel like there may be a easier solution, if not, just throw in whatever works.

The code below is what gets my input box to work:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    checkValue();
});

function checkValue() {
    var message = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    $('#output').html(message);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I strip certain html tags out of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890664/how-can-i-strip-certain-html-tags-out-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if that fits your needs:

```
var message = $('<div/>', {
    html: document.getElementById("userinput").value
}).find(':header').remove().end().html();
```

Or you could use e.g `replaceWith(function(){return '<h>'+this.innerHTML+'</h>';})` instead of `remove()`.

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AVLd/)

Comment: You need to still be able to have tags like `<b>` take effect on the writing? is that possible?

Comment: @minseong That's already the case in posted jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AVLd/ or i don't understand what you mean by "take effect on the writing"?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Have upvoted your answer, it is the better one.

Comment: May I suggest these _very_ slight changes to your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/WfDqM/1/, basically just including the h1 as text rather than an element.

Comment: @WalkOfLife `.find(':header, p, whatever selector here')` then you could filter it in `replaceWith()` by nodeType or using jQuery `is('selector')` method

Comment: @WalkOfLife fixed jsFiddle, you need to use any relevant method for checking: http://jsfiddle.net/5AVLd/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another part to your checkValue function:

```
function checkValue() {
    var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    var message = text.replace(/<h1>/g,"&#60;h1&#62;");
    $('#output').html(message);
}
```

See how I have replaced all h1 elements with [escaped characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) and the text (h1).

This should work and you can repeat it again and again to get rid of everything you don't want, e.g.

```
function checkValue() {
    var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    var check = text.replace(/<h1>/g,"&#60;h1&#62;");
    var check2 = check.replace(/<h2>/g,"&#60;h2&#62;");
    var message = check2.replace(/<table>/g,"&#60;table&#62;")
    $('#output').html(message);
}
```

There is more on the replace function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Here is a different way that I found on this site:

[How can I strip certain html tags out of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890664/how-can-i-strip-certain-html-tags-out-of-a-string)

Comment: you'll replace only first occurence here, you should pass a regex as parameter, not string. BTW, this won't replace e.g `<h1 style="...">`  nor `</h1>`, etc...

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out (first occurence), have updated my answer to fix that but will continue to work on it to solve the other problems.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to try to parse HTML, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/1414562