# Space in input = html line break?

Tags: html, input

A followup question to my previous thread:
[Disable some html output in input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745725/disable-some-html-output-in-input-box)

I just noticed that everytime I add a space in my input, a line break is automatically added (basically the equivilant of `<br>` in html.

So if I typed `Hello I am John` in the input, the output would return:

```
Hello
I 
Am
John
```

I just want the input to space the text and not add a `<br>`
So `Hello I am John` would be `Hello I am John` as it should be.

Hope I made things clear,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was just a margin problem that was pushing my text.

Answer (score 0):

You can had a space just type `&nbsp;`

So If u want to type whitespaces without the `<br>` problem you need to do a javascript function  that replace spaces by `&nbsp;`

```
function removeSpaces()  {
   var str = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML; 
   var res = str.replace(/\s/gi, "&nbsp;");
   document.getElementById("input").innerHTML=res;
}
```

Comment: Here's part of my code, it still isn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z2Jb/ I appreciate your help though and hope that you can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

write your code as follows

```
Hello &nbsp; I &nbsp; am &nbsp; John
```

Comment: That would be annoying for my users.