# Remove HTML element span with class notranslate from string

Tags: javascript

Need to remove specific HTML tag span with class "notranslate", The following solution is removing all HTML tag from my text.

My expected result is: `Deleted String: Adding string: Idea No.<p>d</p> value Details`

```js
var str = 'Idea No.<p>d</p> {{value}} Details';
var addStr = 'Adding string: ' + str.replace('{{', '<span class="notranslate">').replace('}}', '</span>');
console.log('Deleted String: ' + addStr.replace(new RegExp(/<\/?[\w\s="/.':;#-\/\?]+>/gi), ''));
```

Comment: You can try create html element and remove element with these class name. For optimalization you can check if string contains this class name, but I don't know if it satisfies you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I strip certain html tags out of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890664/how-can-i-strip-certain-html-tags-out-of-a-string)

Comment: One of [SO's most seminal posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is regarding the wisdom of parsing HTML with regular expressions. Avoid. Use a proper HTML parser to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it with a RegEx, you can use the below to strip **any** HTML **span** element which **has** the `notranslate` class. It takes into account the fact that you can have other properties on the element and multiple class names. As long as there is a `<span>` with class `notranslate`, it will strip the HTML tag and keep the content.

```
/<span.*?class=(?:"|"(?:[^"]*)\s)notranslate(?:"|\s(?:[^"]*)").*?>(.*?)<\/span>/
```

Working snippet:

```js
let str1 = 'I want <span class="notranslate" data-xyz="whatever">this</span> to be removed.';

console.log('original:', str1);
console.log('modified:', str1.replace(/<span.*?class=(?:"|"(?:[^"]*)\s)notranslate(?:"|\s(?:[^"]*)").*?>(.*?)<\/span>/, "$1"));

let str2 = 'I want <span class="whatever notranslate another-class" data-xyz="whatever">this</span> to be removed.';

console.log('original:', str2);
console.log('modified:', str2.replace(/<span.*?class=(?:"|"(?:[^"]*)\s)notranslate(?:"|\s(?:[^"]*)").*?>(.*?)<\/span>/, "$1"));
```

If you can have multiple occurrences of that tag in the same string, you can add the `g` (global) flag.

```
/<span.*?class=(?:"|"(?:[^"]*)\s)notranslate(?:"|\s(?:[^"]*)").*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g
```

```js
let str1 = 'I want <span class="notranslate" data-xyz="whatever">this</span> but <span class="notranslate" data-xyz="whatever">also this</span> to be removed.';

console.log('original:', str1);
console.log('modified:', str1.replace(/<span.*?class=(?:"|"(?:[^"]*)\s)notranslate(?:"|\s(?:[^"]*)").*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing DOM is complex enough to not write it by hand.

If you can run it in a browser, here is the solution:

```js
var str = 'Idea No.<p>d</p> {{value}} Details';
var addStr = 'Adding string: ' + str.replace('{{', '<span class="notranslate">').replace('}}', '</span>');

const dom = document.createElement('div');
dom.innerHTML = addStr;
const notranslate = dom.getElementsByClassName('notranslate');
for (let elem of notranslate) {
  elem.remove();
}
console.log(dom.innerHTML);
```

Comment: it is the only script, no HTML dom is here.

Comment: Where do you run this script?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a specific HTML tag but to keep the innerHtml,
try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232971/5330419):

```js
var str = 'Idea No.<p>d</p> {{value}} Details';
var addStr = 'Adding string: ' + str.replace('{{', '<span class="notranslate">').replace('}}', '</span>');


const dom = document.createElement('div');
dom.innerHTML = addStr;

const span = dom.getElementsByClassName('notranslate');

while(span.length) {
    var parent = span[0].parentNode;
    while(span[0].firstChild) {
        parent.insertBefore(  span[ 0 ].firstChild, span[0]);
    }
     parent.removeChild(span[0]);
}
console.log(dom.innerHTML); //Adding string: Idea No.<p>d</p> value Details
```

Answer (score -1):

the method replace all tag because you use in RegExp the option 'gi' where 'gi' perform a global case-insensitive replacement. If you what replace a specific class you must define in regExp