# Change th tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any clue how I can access each `th` under `class="CenteredHeader"` to add more parameters via jQuery to `a` tag?

```
<tr class="CenteredHeader">
  <th scope="col"></th>
  <th scope="col">
      <a href="/BoxOffice/Movies/807?sort=MovieName&amp;sortdir=ASC">Pelicula</a>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
      <a href="/BoxOffice/Movies/807?sort=TechnologyName&amp;sortdir=DESC">Tecnologia</a>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: this question can help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369182/how-to-replace-elements-attr-href-with-each-strip-url

Comment: +1 good question. If I vote up on an answer it is only fair to assume it was a good question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.CenteredHeader th a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', function(i, oldhref) {
         return oldhref + '&amp;p1=111'
     });
})​;
```

You can use different parameter to each `a` tag by above solution if you want.

Can also do as [@François Wahl comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951768/change-th-tag-value/11951795#comment15924653_11951795) stated:

```
$('.CenteredHeader th a').attr('href', function(i, oldhref) {
     return oldhref + '&amp;p1=111'
})​;
```

Comment: what is the min version of jQuery that supports setting a attr value with a function? It looks cool :)

Comment: @LiviuT. - Version 1.1 and up. (So _almost_ any version.) You can do the same thing with other methods like `.html()`, `.text()` and `.val()`.

Comment: P.S. Note that you don't need the `.each()` loop if using that syntax of `.attr()`, your `.attr()` callback will be called for each element in the jQuery object...

Comment: @thecodeparadox Thanks man! You read my mind! Awesome answer. It is exactly I need.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I didn't want to edit the answer but you are correct. This works too: `$('.CenteredHeader th a').attr('href', function(i, oldhref) { return oldhref + '&amp;p1=111' });`, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j7AGQ/. @thecodeparadox: feel free to add it to your answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.CenteredHeader th a').attr('href', "/BoxOffice/Movies/807?sort=MovieName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;p1=111")
```

Comment: +1 for single line solution. As far as I understood OP wants to change all the `href` attributes for a tags in each th. This seems to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is appropriate given that the th in the example has two anchors with different href values.

Comment: @nnnnnn: True, it wasn't quite obvious thogh from original post that each row is not going to be set to the same value. If only the end of the text has to change `thecodeparadox`'s answer might be more adabtable alright.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.CenteredHeader a').each(function(index, a) {
  var newHref = $(a).attr('href')+'&key=value';
  $(a).attr('href', newHref );
});
```