# jquery .replace

Tags: jquery, replace

How can I turn this "**-** | " into "**-**" with jQuery?

```
  .replace(/__-__ | /g, '__-__'
```

This also replaces the empty spaces

```
  .replace('__-__ | ', '__-__'
```

This only replaces the first time it occurs

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369182/how-to-replace-elements-attr-href-with-each-strip-url

Comment: You can't! `.replace()` is plain javascript? The first one uses a global regex, and the second one just matches the first occurence in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer helpt me out! :)

```
 .replace(/__-__ \|/g, '__-__')
```

This worked just great!
Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're attempting this in jQuery.  String replace is a javascript string method unless you're talking about replacing DOM elements.

```
input.replace(/- \|/g, '-_-');
```

[See this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/GwSTt/)