# window.location.hash returns hash tag in front of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, hashtag

I have the following code in MVC3 view:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var manager= new Manager();

        manager.doSomeStuff(window.location.hash);
    }
});
```

The interesting thing is that when there is no hash tag in the URL, or there is only a hash tag example:

```
http://localhost:1223/Index/AboutUs

http://localhost:1223/Index/AboutUs#
```

When the `window.location.hash` is empty and the function is not executed.
But when there is some value in the hash tag:

```
http://localhost:1223/Index/AboutUs#categoryId=5&manufacturerId=8
```

The value in the `window.location.hash` is `#categoryId=5&manufacturerId=8`

Can you explain to me why the `#` tag is included in the value and why when there is no value after the `#` tag, the `window.location.hash` is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing much to explain. It is the way it works.

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

**Definition and Usage**

```
The hash property returns the anchor portion of a URL, including the hash sign (#).
```

Comment: Yes, I saw the definition, but it seems somehow strange that the hash sign is returned with the value. That is why I asked the question. Also when you are setting the window.location.hash value, you do not need to add the hash sign to the string.

Answer (score 8):

You can change it if you want by simply changing the hash name:

```
//Your old hash name caught in a variable
var nameHash = location.hash;

//Your new hash name without "#"
var newHashName = nameHash.replace("#","");
```

Comment: This might produce undesirable results if the hash contains another `#` character.

Answer (score 8):

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

This omits the first character of the string, which is the hash tag.

Answer (score 1):

[You can repalce `#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369182/how-to-replace-elements-attr-href-with-each-strip-url) but this way will create conflict and won't work with javascript.

[Here is window.location reference link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Here is different usage examples:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urlHash = window.location.hash;
    var sampleURL = '#categoryId=5&manufacturerId=8';

    if ( urlHash.length > 1 ) {
       //do stuff
    }else{
       //if value is empty, do stuff
    }

    if ( urlHash === sampleURL ) {
       commonResponse();
    }

    $('a').click(function() {
       var target = $(this).attr('href');

       if (target === sampleURL ) {
          commonResponse();
       }    
    });

    function commonResponse() {
       //alert('ok');
    }
});
```