# Using .attr to change beginning of src property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, attributes, append

This changes

1. "https://www.youtube.com/channel/blah" to
2. "https://www.youtube.com/channel/blah/videos"

```js
$(".yt-user-name.spf-link").attr("href", function(i, href) {  
    return href + '/videos';
});
```

I was wondering how I can change "https://www.youtube ..." to "https://www.m.youtube ..."

Possible solutions(?):

1. [How to replace element's attr href with each ? // strip url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369182)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/179717/2038928

Answer (score 3):

you can use .replace to replace the part of string:

```
$(".yt-user-name.spf-link").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href.replace("www.you","www.m.you") 
});
```

Comment: @computerguy what exactly is the problem? This is the right answer. You just need to add your `+ '/videos'` to the end.

Comment: I am using tampermonkey with firefox. This is the code I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/computerguy/adrxkqp1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('https://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.m.youtube.com');
    });
});
```